# Is running a bare metal hypervisor on a new laptop for commercial use feasible?

Tags: laptop, virtual-machine, hypervisor, bare-metal

Every time I search for advice on a bare metal hypervisor, people usually recommend against it, but I am still curious if I can/should try it when I buy a new laptop in the next month. I've used VMs a lot, but the idea of having a bare metal hypervisor in which I can choose what to run at any one time is quite attractive. Which hypervisor should I choose for a commercial use on a laptop and more importantly what are the downsides to running such software instead of a standard OS?

Comment: Define commercial use

Comment: Sorry, I might've worded it incorrectly, but I meant it as personal use as in a personal laptop and not something which is used for a server for example.

Comment: So using a laptop for work?

Comment: For both work and personal use in my free time.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your single biggest problem is going to be power management.  The hypervisor is almost certainly not going to be designed for power efficiency, nor will it probably be able to communicate with the hardware for things like battery state.

Unless you like having a laptop that's tethered to a power line, I'd recommend you decide on a primary operating environment and install that OS on the laptop first and use a Type-2 hypervisor for your VMs.